# How to change \subsection such that text follows immediately?

Tags: sectioning, sections-paragraphs

Consider this example:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,oneside]{article}
\begin{document}
\section{Xavier functions}  
\subsection{} %% \textbf{1.1} 
We define the \textit{Xavier functions} for a complex value $z$ as
\[ \chi(z) = \exp(z). \]
\end{document}
```

The question is: how to start the text of the subsection 
immediately after the subsection numbering?

[image]

(You can simulate this by replacing \subsection{} by \textbf{1.1} in the above code.)

Comment: Don't misuse subsections for that, better use a `theorem`-based environment with automatic numbering.

Comment: If you absolutely want to use a subsection, the `runin` style of `titlesec` is your friend.

Comment: I read "don't misuse", "if you absolutely want", "If you really want". What's wrong with this? Why a different approach?

Comment: if you don't want a title, that possibility must be accommodated by the applicable definitions.  try inserting `\ignorespaces` as the "title" to avoid both the defined space between subsection number and heading and the space inserted after the heading. (i'm not in a position to test this, so don't know what side effects it might have if subsections are included in a toc.)

Comment: @SophiaAntipolis: To see why misusing `\subsection` like this doesn't make sense, print a TOC. A title has special meaning, and what you want doesn't look like a title but a numbered theorem/definition, so use a `theorem` environment.

Comment: @You -- i've seen documents where beyond a certain level only numbers were used (consistently!) for segmenting, and those lower levels were not included in the toc.  theorem objects have special meaning, and may not be appropriate for such unnumbered subsections; besides, a theorem object almost always has a distinct heading, not just a number, so that doesn't solve the problem.  the best approach i can suggest here is to omit heading text from *all* divisions at this level, and omit them from the toc -- be consistent.

Comment: This paper will not have a TOC (and yes I see there might be problems with this). The resulting 'style' is similar to the style of Jean Dieudonne's Elements d'Analyse. These are subsections without titles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this ?. But as mentioned this will not be pretty if you use a table of contents beyond level 1. You could of course include a short bit of title or the start of your text within the \subsection{}

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,oneside]{article}

\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{#1}
\titleformat{\subsection}[runin]{\normalsize\sffamily\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{1em}{#1} 

\begin{document}
\section{Xavier functions}  
\subsection{}
We define the \textit{Xavier functions} for a complex value $z$ as
\[ \chi(z) = \exp(z). \]

\subsection{Here is another}
starting with a title. 

\end{document}
```

[image]

You could also I guess use a Table of Contents by entering stuff into the optional tag, something like:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,oneside]{article}

\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{#1}
\titleformat{\subsection}[runin]{\normalsize\sffamily\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{1em}{#1} 

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Xavier functions}  
\subsection[The world defined]{}
We define the \textit{Xavier functions} for a complex value $z$ as
\[ \chi(z) = \exp(z). \]

\subsection{Here is another}
starting with a title. 

\subsection[Title for table of contents]{}

Cupim tail hamburger filet mignon, shankle drumstick corned beef turducken jowl shank. Pork chop rump pastrami filet mignon, spare ribs tri-tip flank. Tongue strip steak kielbasa ham hock cupim flank. Spare ribs beef capicola, cow ground round rump bresaola flank cupim filet mignon ball tip leberkas doner. Frankfurter pork chop short loin cupim. Shank chicken tenderloin biltong filet mignon t-bone flank pork chop short loin bresaola ham hock. 

Pork belly kevin pancetta meatball, meatloaf hamburger salami capicola pork spare ribs.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I get errors with \listoftables: Undefined control sequence. \listoftables Missing number, treated as zero. \listoftables Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted). \listoftables Package titlesec Error: Entered in horizontal mode. \listoftables Package xcolor Error: Undefined color `bgheadcol'. \listoftables

Comment: But otherwise it works!

Comment: Sorry I have some redundant prive code in there -- will fix it shortly

Comment: Removed the reference to the color - but your errors will have to do with other things.

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer of Aubrey Blumsohn with some minor modifications. Aubrey's answer uses a different font for the enumeration. But more importantly this style needs less vertical space between subsections. Here I list the modifications for the sake of completeness with some test code.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,oneside]{article}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}{\normalfont\fontsize{12}{11}\selectfont\bfseries}{\thesection}{10pt}{#1}[\vspace{10pt}]
\titleformat{\subsection}[runin]{\fontsize{10}{10}\bfseries\vspace{-10pt}}{\thesubsection}{6pt}{#1}
\newcommand{\postsection}{\vspace{-10pt}\hspace{18pt}}
\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents\bigskip\bigskip\hrule\bigskip
    \section{Basic functions} 
    \postsection The horizontal separation between label and body and must be a length. In fact, using it can lead to impredictable results. Anyway, if you need them, you may use them. 
    \subsection[Trigonometric functions]{} 
    For instance the functions $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$ are basic trigonometric functions.
    \section{Special functions} 
    \subsection[Xavier functions]{} 
    We define the \textit{Xavier functions} for a complex value $z$ as
    \[\chi(z) = \exp(z).\]
    The horizontal separation between label and body and must be a length. In fact, using it can lead to impredictable results. Anyway, if you need them, you may use them. 
    \subsection[Annabelle functions]{} 
    We define the \textit{Annabelle functions} for a complex value $z$ as
    \[\alpha(z) = \log(z).\]
    The horizontal separation between label and body and must be a length. In fact, using it can lead to impredictable results. Anyway, if you need them, you may use them. 
    \subsection[Theorem]{Theorem}
    \textit{Xavier functions and Annabelle functions are related by}
    \[z = \chi(\alpha(z)).\]
    The horizontal separation between label and body and must be a length. In fact, using it can lead to impredictable results. Anyway, if you need them, you may use them. 
\end{document}
```